# Basic SQL Update statement not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm working on a simple, small project for a class - a mock-database (built using phpMyAdmin) with an accompanying web application for user input, to allow for searching/appending/updating said database. Searching and Appending is working perfectly, but updating is giving me grief.

I have error messages set to display to help in the debugging process, and although they've popped up for previous issues in this project, they haven't shown up for this particular problem.

My code looks like this:

```
$sth = "UPDATE adjunct_number
        SET FIRSTNAME = '.$updateInformation.'
        WHERE 700NUMBER = '.$updateCriteria.';";

(I tried echoing $sth right here, nothing displayed!)

$sth = $db->prepare($sth);
$sth->execute();
```

$updateInformation and $updateCriteria are both being pulled from an HTML form's text boxes successfully. (I'll enter Drew and 700123456 into the form as test data.) I tested that $updateInformation and $updateCriteria ARE in fact being successfully captured using this statement:

```
echo $updateInformation . ", " . $updateCriteria
```

Which yields the following output:

```
Drew, 700123456
```

I'll enter the following query into phpMyAdmin to test it first.

```
UPDATE adjunct_number
SET FIRSTNAME = 'DREW'
WHERE 700NUMBER = 700482306
```

It always works in phpMyAdmin, as expected, 100% of the time... however, the exact same update command never works when I send it through via PHP, which confusions me greatly. The only thing I can think of is an overlooked PHP typo in my SQl statement, but at this point in time I've been staring at it for so long that I could use a fresh set of eyes! Why is it that when I tried to echo $sth, no sql statement was displayed? Any insight from this wonderful community would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No need of `;` in your query. You are not in interactive session
- You are subject to SQL injection.
- No need of quote with parameterized query.

Here's a suggestion how you you could do it.

```
$query = "UPDATE adjunct_number SET FIRSTNAME = ? WHERE 700NUMBER = ?";
$sth = $db->prepare($query);
$sth->execute( array( $updateInformation, $updateCriteria ) );
```

Comment: While your answer is good, and does provide him with a way to correctly format the query, it doesn't actually point out the problem with the way he was originally doing it, @marc-b does a good job describing what was wrong, although it's a little confusing, the basic idea is, he wasn't actually leaving the original string so he was querying with the literal values ".$updateInformation." and ".$updateCriteria."

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn basic PHP strings:

```
$sth = "UPDATE adjunct_number
       ^---start of PHP string
        SET FIRSTNAME = '.$updateInformation.'
        WHERE 700NUMBER = '.$updateCriteria.';";
                                              ^---end of PHP string
```

That means your query is doing `... SET FIRSTNAME = '.foo.' ...`, with the `.` embedded literally within the query. That means your `where` clause will never match any records.

Since you're using `"` for the quotes, you don't NEED to use the `.` at all:

```
$sth = "UPDATE adjunct_number
        SET FIRSTNAME = '$updateInformation'
        WHERE 700NUMBER = '$updateCriteria';";
```

or you should properly exit the string first:

```
$sth = "UPDATE adjunct_number
        SET FIRSTNAME = '" . $updateInformation . "'
        WHERE 700NUMBER = '" . $updateCriteria . "';";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed single and double quotes. Update it to the following:

```
$sth = "UPDATE adjunct_number
    SET FIRSTNAME = ".$updateInformation."
    WHERE 700NUMBER = ".$updateCriteria.";
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try using the symbol (" ` ")backtick for column names and tables

```
UPDATE `adjunct_number`
SET `FIRSTNAME` = 'DREW'
WHERE `700NUMBER` = 700482306
```

Comment: why? backticks are only necessary to escape reserved words. none of the field/table names are reserved words, so this is basically pointless.

Comment: No, I had done a project in PHP where I had to write the column name and the tables using backticks or else it would not recognize them